# transferring between terminals in Bole International airport (Addis Ababa)

Tags: transit, airport-terminals, ethiopia, addis-ababa, add

I am arriving into Addis Ababa through Terminal 1 and I need to transfer to Terminal 2 for a connecting flight.

Do I need to clear immigration for this? Or is it alright to stay airside with the need to apply for transit visa?

My flights are in one ticket, but different airlines. Going to ADD, I will be taking ET (terminal 2). From ADD, I will be taking TK (terminal 1).
Passport is Philippines.

Comment: Is this for a connecting flight within Ethiopia or are you transferring to another country?

Comment: Connecting to another country, Turkiye

Answer (score 2):

[This is the statement](https://www.ethiopiaimmigration.org/faq/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-ethiopia) from the institution that sells e-visas for Ethopia:

> Do I need a transit visa for Ethiopia? **No. You do not need to obtain a visa for transit flights. That means you have to stay at the airport
> to wait for the next flight to your destination.** If you wish to leave
> the airport to visit Addis Ababa for some time, you must apply for a
> tourist eVisa or visit the Embassy to get a transit visa. In this
> case, Ethiopia Immigration Services suggest you obtain an Ethiopia
> eVisa because it is straightforward. The application process is
> relatively simple, and the visa fee is charged based on the validity
> duration.

Since it says "stay at the airport," it must be assumed that there is a possibility to transit between terminals without the need for a visa or clearing immigration. Hope this helps.